# why cannot duplicate array using Python?

Tags: python, arrays, dictionary, duplicates

Help! I have a big problem using Python. 
  We know in Python if `A=[1,2,3]` and if `B=A`, `B[1]=10`, then `A=[1,10,3]`.
  To fix this, we can `import copy` and `B =copy.copy(A)` or `B=A[:]`.
  In both cases, doing `B[1]=10` won't change `A`.

Now I extend `A` as a dictionary, and `A[1]=[1,2,3]`. Doing

```
  A = {1:[1,2,3]}
  A[2] = A[1][:]
  for j in range(len(A[1])):
      A[2].append(4)
  print (A[2])
  print (A[1])
```

the result shows

```
  [1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4]
  [1, 2, 3]
```

It only changes `A[2]`, not `A[1]`. So it is good.
   But If I do `A[1] = [[1],[2],[3]]`, and

```
  A = {1:[[1],[2],[3]]}
  A[2] = A[1][:]
  for j in range(len(A[1])):
      A[2][j].append(4)    
  print (A[2])
  print (A[1])
```

which instead gives me

```
  [[1, 4], [2, 4], [3, 4]]
  [[1, 4], [2, 4], [3, 4]]
```

not

```
  [[1, 4], [2, 4], [3, 4]]
  [[1], [2], [3]]
```

where `A[1]` was changed. Anyone can help me figure this out? I even use `A[2] = copy.copy(A[1])` still doesn't work. Thank you very much for the solution!!!!

Comment: Have you tried ``copy.deepcopy()``?

Comment: use https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy

Comment: @Graham, thanks! yes `copy.deepcopy()` works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The explantation for this behavior is that you're only copying at the first level. When you set up your dictionary as

```
>>> A = {1:[[1],[2],[3]]}
>>> A[2] = A[1][:]
```

then `A[2]` is an independent copy of `A[1]` *only at the first level* (`id` gives the memory address of an object):

```
>>> id(A[1])
4347137160
>>> id(A[2])
4347154056
```

However, respective elements of `A[1]` and `A[2]` are still references to the same object:

```
>>> id(A[1][0])
4346993992
>>> id(A[2][0])
4346993992
```

As pointed out in other comments, you would have to make a deepcopy to also copy at the second level:

```
>>> import copy
>>> A[2] = copy.deepcopy(A[1])
>>> id(A[1][0])
4346993992
>>> id(A[2][0])
4349177096
```

Comment: what about if I have `A ={1:[[[1],[2],[3]],[4]]}` (three levels)? should `copy.deepcopy()` still  work? In this case, always using `copy.deepcopy()` is a safe way?

Comment: yes, `deepcopy` works recursively to an arbitrary number of levels

Comment: great! this is super-important to me! a ton of thanks!